# "Unable to parse rubocopy response" error in Intellij when loading a custom java program into jruby

Tags: jruby

A `jruby` project was created in `Intellij` and a small `java` module to build the "hello world" java program that will be invoked by the `jruby` module.  After building the `jrubyjava` module we can see that the `jruby_hello.rb` is "happy" that both the `jdk` - from `java.util.TreeSet` and the custom classes from `com.example.[CallMe, ISpeaker]` are accessible to the `jruby_hello.rb` script:

[image]

However - when running the `jruby` code the following error occurs:

[image]

Here is the `rubocop` response:

> Error:jruby.jar is  /usr/local/opt/jruby/libexec/lib/jruby.jar
>   {"metadata":{"rubocop_version":"0.79.0","ruby_engine":"jruby","ruby_version":"2.5.7","ruby_patchlevel":"0","ruby_platform":"java"},"files":[{"path":"jruby_hello.rb","offenses":[{"severity":"convention","message":"Missing magic comment `# frozen_string_literal: true`.","cop_name":"Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment","corrected":false,"correctable":true,"location":{"start_line":1,"start_column":1,"last_line":1,"last_column":1,"length":1,"line":1,"column":1}},{"severity":"convention","message":"Prefer single-quoted strings when you don't need string interpolation or special symbols.","cop_name":"Style/StringLiterals","corrected":false,"correctable":true,"location":{"start_line":1,"start_column":9,"last_line":1,"last_column":14,"length":6,"line":1,"column":9}},{"severity":"convention","message":"Prefer single-quoted strings when you don't need string interpolation or special symbols.","cop_name":"Style/StringLiterals","corrected":false,"correctable":true ...

[image]

We can notice that buried in the error output is

```
  "message":"Missing magic comment `# frozen_string_literal: true`."
```

What is needed for fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding that string at the top of the file seems to have resolved the issue

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
require "java"
```

[image]